# How to release memory when ContentPage is popped in MAUI app when there are no explicit lingering event handlers?

Tags: memory-management, navigation, maui

In my app, when a button is pressed on a ContentPage (CP1), I create a new ContentPage (CP2) and push it onto the stack very simply like so...

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CP2(param1, param2));
```

CP2 consumes a lot of memory, ~400MB. When CP2 is displayed, if I click the back arrow  to navigate back to CP1, memory isn't freed. Each time I navigate from CP1 to CP2, another ~400MB is allocated and not freed when I pop CP2 off the navigation stack. Rather quickly, the app is jettisoned by the device for excessive memory use. CP2 doesn't subscribe to any events other than those generated by it's own controls. It does use a custom built ContentView. However, that view doesn't subscribe to any events nor does it use any unmanaged resources.

Here is the xaml for CP2 (really named MyWaxBoxAddItemsV):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:custom_components="clr-namespace:FasterWaxer.CustomComponents"
             x:Class="FasterWaxer.MyWaxBoxAddItemsV"
             Title="MyWaxBoxAddItemsV">
    
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BrandCatalog}" Margin="7,0,5,0">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="65" ColumnDefinitions="*,60">
                    <!--<custom_components:CatalogItem Grid.Column="0" />-->
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnAddWaxBoxItemTapped" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image Source="{Binding AddActionIconFileName}" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="23" WidthRequest="28" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code behind that defines the only event handler to which CP2 subscribes:

```
public partial class MyWaxBoxAddItemsV : ContentPage
{
    private readonly MyWaxBoxAddItemsVM vm;

    public MyWaxBoxAddItemsV(MyWaxBoxVM waxBox, WaxBrandCatalogItemVM brandCatalog)
    {
        vm = new MyWaxBoxAddItemsVM(waxBox, brandCatalog);
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private async void OnAddWaxBoxItemTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null) return;
        var item = (WaxCatalogItemVM)e.Parameter;

        if (item.IsInMyWaxBox)
        {
            string prompt = new($"Remove {item.BrandName} {item.ModelName}?");
            if (await DisplayAlert(prompt, string.Empty, "Remove", "Cancel"))
            {
                vm.WaxBox.RemoveItem(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vm.WaxBox.AddItem(item);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

custom_components:CatalogItem is a ContentView that displays a bunch of formatted data. You can see, I commented it out in the xaml above. When I do so, the memory consumption is less each time CP2 is rendered. However, still, the memory isn't freed.

There are ObservableObjects and ObservableCollections in MyWaxBoxAddItemsVM (the ViewModel for "CP2"). There are no event handlers in the CP2 MyWaxBoxAddItemsVM hierarchy.

I spent hours pouring through Microsoft articles, stackoverflow posts, etc. I see a lot of info related to using IDisposable and other solutions that almost all relate to unsubscribing event handlers. In my case, I don't have any event handlers I'm aware of to unsubscribe. There are event handlers in other classes that change the ObservableObjects that are part of CP2's ViewModel. I keep thinking my problem may be related to this.
Any guidance on why memory isn't being freed when CP2 is popped from the navigation stack? Could it be related to CP2 having ObservableObjects in its hierarchy? How can I free memory when CP2 is popped?

Jul 2: Adding info regarding something else I tried...

I tried to implement MyWaxBoxAddItemsV (CP2) as IDisposable. Dispose() sets vm and BindingContext to null. CP1 calls MyWaxBoxAddItemsV.Dispose() on the previous instance of CP2 before creating a new instance of CP2. This results in no change in the memory consumption pattern.

As always, I will be deeply grateful for guidance that gets me to a solution.

Comment: Do you need to create a new instance of CP2 every time?

Comment: I believe so. Each invocation of CP2 is with a different data set and different number of items to render in the CollectionView. I’ve assumed I can’t use the same ContentPage instance in that situation. That is, BrandCatalog changes each time CP2 is rendered.

Comment: Are you using Shell or NavigationPage for navigation? This is determined in App.xaml.cs by `MainPage = new AppShell();` or similar for NavPage. If its Shell, it would be interesting to change to NavigationPage. To find out if it is a Shell bug re Nav stack. You might also examine the Nav Stack, make sure the page is actually removed.

Comment: Can you show your navigation logic?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I am using Shell. I considered trying to use GoToAsync() instead of PushAsync() or switching from Shell to NavPage but decided to try resolving the current issue before rearchitecting my navigation. I checked the Nav Stack and CP2 is no longer on the stack after I click its back arrow.

Comment: @o_w - using Shell, my MainPage has 4 tabs. Clicking TabA invokes PushAsync(CP0). Clicking a Grid item on CP0 invokes PushAsync(CP1). Clicking a Grid item on CP1, invokes PushAsync(CP2) as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched for "Memory Management Maui" and found several bug reports related to the horrible memory leak I'm having. You can see them here: [Massive memory leak in CollectionView while scrolling](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10560), [Memory leaks EVERYWHERE](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12039), [[core] fix memory leaks in bindings](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13327).

A fix was claimed to have been included in the latest preview release of .NET/MAUI (8.0.0-preview.5.8529). I installed this SDK, however, I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac and it's not compatible with .NET 8.0. So, I haven't been able to see if the issue has been resolved yet. I'll report back here as soon as I learn more or find a fix.

Comment: I upgraded to .NET 8.0 and have the same issue. No improvement.